# ansible how to use a variable in a for loop

Tags: yaml, ansible

I have an ansible task like this:

```
- name: coreos network configuration
    {% for interface in argument['interfaces'] %}
      {% if argument[interface]['role'] == 'ingest' %}
  script: netconfiginput.sh -i {{interface}} #incorrect, how to get the value of the interface variable of the for loop?
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

While running this ansible task, I pass a JSON string argument:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars 'argument={"interfaces":["eno1","eno2","ep8s0"],"eno2":{"role":"ingest"}}' network-config.yml
```

What I want to do is, loop through the JSON array called `interfaces`, which are a list of network interfaces, when the `role` of the interface is called `ingest`, I run a script and pass the network interface as an argument to the script, my implementation is incorrect, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `with_items` and replace variable name with `item`.

A rough example:

```
name: task name
script: netconfiginput.sh -i {{ item }}
with_items: interfaces_array
when: some_role == 'ingest'
```

To understand what kind of data you're sending, use the following:

```
name: debugging
debug:
  var: argument
```

That should show you, amongst other things, whether or not Ansible is considering parts of your variable's structure valid arrays or not.

Comment: I tried this, but I got error `with_items expects a list or a set`. And it should be `argument[some interface]['role']`.

Comment: I've modified my answer just slightly. If you aren't passing an array, then you should use `debug` in a previous command to see how it is being passed.

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 can be used in ansible templates, not in playbooks.
Ansible supports looping over hashes. You can try this:

```
---
- hosts: <test_servers> # replace with your hosts
  vars:
    interfaces:
      eno1:
        role: null
      eno2:
        role: ingest
      ep8s0:
        role: null
  tasks:
    - name: coreos network configuration
      script: netconfiginput.sh -i {{ item.key }}
      with_dict: "{{interfaces}}"
      when: item.value.role == "ingest"
```